# How do I retreat from an expedition with all my resources in Loop Hero?

Tags: loop-hero

I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to retreat from an expedition without losing  any resources, and I haven't had much luck tracking down an answer.

My assumption was that beating the boss would allow me retreat with all resources, and sure enough, upon beating my first boss I was given the option to retreat with all my resources. I decided to stay, though, since I wanted to farm more... only to no longer have the option to retreat with all my resources.

I ended up dying before finishing another loop. It doesn't make sense to me that the game would allow me to continue exploring after the boss is dead if doing so would result in me losing resources, so there must be something I'm overlooking.

How can I retreat from an expedition without losing any resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To retreat with *all* of your resources, you must retreat while on the camp tile (the one you start on, and heal at each loop). As @Wrigglenite's answer says, you have to click the retreat button in the bottom right.

You'll know you can retreat with everything if the retreat icon is glowing like so:

[image]

Compared to the normal button which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: To add: the ability to safely retreat seems to be active on the tile before the camp, if there is no enemy or you've beaten it. Additionally, you can press and hold the retreat button for about 2 seconds at any time to activate safely stopping at the camp when you reach it.

Comment: @Oso interesting, good to know! I normally only notice it _right_ as my hero touches the tiles first pixel.

Answer (score 6):

You can retreat from an expedition with all your resources by pressing the button in the lower right corner of the screen when you're standing on the camp tile.

If you hold the button down some gears will pop up, which indicates it'll give you the option automatically so you don't miss it (you still have the option of staying).

Comment: Also if you are worried of missing your chance to retreat at the camp tile, there is an option in the settings to automatically pause the game each time you reach the camp tile.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you wanted to retreat while keeping all your resources, you would have to retreat only when you are on *or adjacent to* your campfire tile.

On the other hand, if you were not by your campfire, the only other way to keep all your resources is to use the **Orb of Immortality** when retreating. To use it, you would click on the "Take All" option while in the retreat dialog.

[image: retreat dialog]

To get more orbs, you would have to [defeat the chapter boss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/383084).

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers: I'd recommend turning on "Pause at the end of each loop" in the options.

[image: Pause at the end of each loop]

This will pause the game every time you touch the campfire, ensuring you don't accidentally pass it and begin another loop *(causing you to lose resources if you die or retreat early)*